# How to update the todo list item in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am using react and redux to write a todolist app.
Here is my initial state:

```
export const initialState = {
todoList:[
    {
        taskId:1
        task: 'gym'
        completed: true
    },
    {
        taskId:2
        task: 'buy dinner'
        completed: false
    }
]
}

const todoReducer = (state=initialState,action) => {
switch(action.type){
    case UPDATE_TODO:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            todoList: state.todoList.map(todo =>
                {
                    return todo.taskId === action.payload.taskId ?
                    Object.assign({},todo, {
                        task: action.payload.task,
                        completed: action.payload.completed
                    }) : todo
                }
            )
        })
    default: 
        return state;
}
}
export default todoReducer;
```

If I want to update the second task to 'buy book' and change completed to true, how can I add code in my reducer? The code above is not working now. Not sure the reason. Could anyone help?

Comment: You're setting the default value of the `state` parameter to an empty array. It should be equal to `initialState`. Also, in your logic for `UPDATE_TODO`, `todo.taskId` is `undefined`. It should be `todo.id`.

Comment: @khan Thanks for replying. Those are typos when I edit this thread. I changed them now.

Comment: There is already React/redux tutorial for exactly this:  https://redux.js.org/basics/example

Comment: @jcklopp I saw the one you mentioned. I used the syntax in the 'TOGGLE_TODO' to update my todo list but got error of 'map is undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:**

**reducer**

```js
const initialState = {
  todoList: [
    {
      taskId: 1,
      task: "gym",
      completed: true
    },
    {
      taskId: 2,
      task: "buy dinner",
      completed: false
    }
  ]
};

const todoReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE_TODO':
      const { payload } = action;
      return {
        ...state,
        todoList: state.todoList.map(item => {
          if (item.taskId === payload.taskId) {
            return {
              ...item,
              task: payload.task,
              completed: payload.completed
            };
          } else {
            return item;
          }
        })
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**Unit test:**

```js
const output = todoReducer(initialState, {type: 'UPDATE_TODO', payload: {
    taskId: 1,
        task: "newTask",
        completed: true
}});
console.log('output', output);
```

**test output:**

```js
output { todoList:
   [ { taskId: 1, task: 'newTask', completed: true },
     { taskId: 2, task: 'buy dinner', completed: false } ] }
```

Comment: it shd work... i have updated my answer with a unit test .... check your code and co-relate it ...  still doesn't work then update ur qn with more code/details